# Facebook sharing, Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share photo + description + link via Facebook in my android application even if there is no native Facebook application. I already done all steps in [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android).  I implemented Facebook Login in my app with publish_actions permission. Now I want to create custom interface and share photo + description + link, but I don't understand how. In tutorial they said:

"Build a custom interface that posts to the Graph API endpoint /me/feed

Implement Facebook Login in your app

Request the publish_actions permission when people log into your app"

Sure, I have done steps 2 and 3 and start reading about Graph API and maybe I am stupid or documentation kinda awful, but I didn't found a answer. They are talking about some Graph actions (that also doesn't work even if I copy tutorial examples), but I simply want add description and link to `SharePhoto` for example. How can I do it?

P.S. Here is my code from tutorials:

```
public void fcShare() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(WorkWithImage.loadBitmap(context, images.get(currentSlide).getImagePath())).build();
    ArrayList<SharePhoto> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    photos.add(sharePhoto);
    final SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().setPhotos(photos).build();
    if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
        ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        shareDialog.show(sharePhotoContent);
    } else if (hasPublishPermission()) {
        ShareApiPg(sharePhotoContent, shareCallback);
    } else {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        ShareApiPg(sharePhotoContent, shareCallback);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

                    }


                });
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained why/how it doesn't work. Please edit your question and add that information as well. As a side note, you shouldn't need to use  "publish_actions" (& Facebook Login) to share content using the share dialog; using the share dialog is enough. For the dialog to work you don't even need to have the Facebook app installed.

Comment: I need publish_actions to share images without native Facebook app.
I can't explain why it doesn't work bcs I don't how to do it, Facebook documentation is awful =(

Comment: You should add a description of either an exception that you're getting, or (if that doesn't happen) describe what the above code *does* do, and in what way that behavior deviates from what you *want*